# pymssql.connect() error: "adaptive server is unavailable or does not exist"

Tags: python, mysql, pymssql

I set up a local MySQL using the MySQL workbench. Is there something I haven't configured properly? I know I'm using the right parameters inside the connect() function.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong module. `mssql` is not `mysql`.

Comment: `pymssql` is for accessing a Microsoft SQL-Server database.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, `pymssql` is for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server.

To connect to MySQL, I've had best luck from Python with the `mysql-connector-python` library:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/2.0.html

To install from Python with pip (recommended):

```
pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python
```

Good luck!